# can't enter values into assigned matrix

Tags: c, malloc

i'm trying to add values to my assigned matrix but there is a constant faliure and visual studio annoces an error and stops runing.
can an se what my problem is?

```
'#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanMath(int,int,int);
void main()
{
    int  i,n,m,**arr;
    printf("enter the size of the rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter the size of the coloms\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);


    arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }
    scanMath(arr[n][m],n,m);
    free(arr);
}
void scanMath(int arr,int R,int C)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
    '
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message given by the compiler? Do that, and if you don't understand it then post it here.

Comment: I recommend reading more about pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanMath(int **,int,int);
int main()
{
    int  i,n,m,**arr;
    printf("enter the size of the rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter the size of the coloms\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);


    arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }
    scanMath(arr,n,m);
    free(arr);
}
void scanMath(int **arr,int R,int C)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<R; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<C; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

There you go. Since you declared it as `int **arr`, and the prototype is the same, merely passing the variable name is enough.

Comment: Oopsie. Didn't look at it so closely ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function as

```
scanMath(arr, n, m);
```

Because the function accepts `int **`. Passing `arr[m][n]` will pass only one element, also it is beyond the allocated bounds.

Comment: What did you change in the allocation relative to the original?

Comment: Actually nothing. I misread the original post wrote  `arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int**));` . Corrected the answer.